# how to convert giant numbers to pure number in JS

Tags: javascript, numbers

how to convert this giant number 7.125693126643573e+26 to pure number in JS without any scientific notation

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in function Number

```
  let number=Number("7.125693126643573E26")
```

you can also convert it using Math

```
 let number=("7.125693126643573e+26")
 parts = String(number).toLowerCase().split('e'), 
 e = parts.pop(),
 l = Math.abs(e), 
 sign = e/l,
 coeff_array = parts[0].split('.');

 var dec = coeff_array[1];
 if(dec) l = l - dec.length;
 num = coeff_array.join('') + new Array(l+1).join('0');

       alert(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.toLocaleString`

```
 var a=7.125693126643573E26;
    console.log(a.toLocaleString()); `//output -> 712,569,312,664,357,300,000,000,000`




 console.log(a.toLocaleString('aa', { useGrouping: false })); `//output -> 712569312664357300000000000`
```

This will remove grouping also.

But it will make your number a string.

Comment: Nice and simple if you don't care about commas.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, if the number is provided in scientific notation it'll probably be too large to use integers to represent it without integer overflow occurring.  Use string functions to break the scientific notation number apart and construct a new string.

```js
const largeNumber = "7.125693126643573E+26"

const [digit, decimal] = largeNumber.toLowerCase().split(".");
const [decimals, power] = decimal.split('e+');
const zerosToFill = power - decimals.length;
const zeros = Array(zerosToFill).fill(0);

const fullNumber = [digit, decimals, ...zeros].join('');

console.log(`${largeNumber} => ${fullNumber}`);
```